# VBA Run two Commands at once together Beep Command

Tags: vba, audio, command, beep

I have made a program that generates frequencies using the Beep statement.

For example: `Beep(Val(FreqTestTxt.Text), Val(DurLbl.Text) * 1000)`

What I need to do though is to Generate 2 frequencies at once. How can it be done?

Comment: VBA runs in a single thread, not asynchronously.

Comment: This isn't possible using VBA.

Comment: Your code doesn't run. `beep` is a sub that takes no parameters. So no brackets and no parameters. This page may help you - https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-play-midi-sounds-with-vba.html.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was hoping it would work.